# Adding items to the taskbar application menu

Tags: c#, winforms, taskbar

I have an application. I would like to add my particular items to the right-click application's taskbar menu via C#. I want to add both permanent items and temporary items.

If I haven't made you to understand, this is the menu I am talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This feature is called a JumpList and is for Windows 7. It is part of the Microsoft API. How to use this with C# has been documented thoroughly [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103913/How-to-Create-a-Custom-Jumplist-with-Custom-Events) and [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Windows-7-Jump-Lists).

In order to be able to deal with Jumplist classes in Windows Forms, you'd have to include these DLLs (`Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.dll` and `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.dll`) in your project. You can get them from [this CodeProject project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103913/How-to-Create-a-Custom-Jumplist-with-Custom-Events) or you can download the Open source library from [WindowsAPICodePack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) which includes the source code that can be used to access Windows 7 and Windows Vista features. You will need to add two usings at the top of your code:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Taskbar;
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell;
```

Any `Jumplist` consists of categories and each category has its own `Jumptask`s. There are two types of `Jumptask`s supported till now by WindowsAPICodePack; the `JumplistLink`  and `JumplistSeperator`. A `Jumptask` represents an action to be performed by the user like openning a new instance of the application or launching another program. These `Jumptask`s are grouped in categories called `JumplistCustomCategories`.