# Taskmanager Icon Options

Tags: c#, windows, user-interface, jump-list

When you right-click the Skype icon in the taskbar while Skype is running, it has a little group in the "CloseWindow" popup thing titled Tasks, which contains options to sign out or quit Skype.

[image]

How would I go about doing this in C#? Thanks.

Comment: Those are called "Jump Lists" do a little web searching. Also see this: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Microsofts Windows API Code Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack). For an example on the exact way to implement it in your case, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7trainingcourse_win7taskbarmanaged_topic2.aspx) tutorial will guide you through all the steps!
The tutorial will show you how to do make the same thing Skype and windows media player use very quickly.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478089/adding-items-to-the-taskbar-application-menu/13478161#13478161):

This feature is called a JumpList and is for Windows 7. It is part of the Microsoft API. How to use this with C# has been documented thoroughly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478089/adding-items-to-the-taskbar-application-menu/13478161#13478161) and [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Windows-7-Jump-Lists).

In order to be able to deal with Jumplist classes in Windows Forms, you'd have to include these DLLs (`Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.dll` and `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.dll`) in your project. You can get them from [this CodeProject project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103913/How-to-Create-a-Custom-Jumplist-with-Custom-Events) or you can download the Open source library from [WindowsAPICodePack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) which includes the source code that can be used to access Windows 7 and Windows Vista features. You will need to add two usings at the top of your code:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Taskbar;
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell;
```

Any `Jumplist` consists of categories and each category has its own `Jumptask`s. There are two types of `Jumptask`s supported till now by WindowsAPICodePack; the `JumplistLink`  and `JumplistSeperator`. A `Jumptask` represents an action to be performed by the user like openning a new instance of the application or launching another program. These `Jumptask`s are grouped in categories called `JumplistCustomCategories`.