# Add more items in context menu (that is displayed when we right click on icon in task bar )

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a small application. I would like to add more items to the right click menu that we get when we right click icon on task bar. How can we do that?

like we can see options for google chrome when we right click on icon in taskbar.

**image description here**

[image]

Comment: Can you mention what research you have done so far? Code snippets will be helpful.

Comment: For hint, please go through https://stackoverflow.com/a/13478161/4222487 and https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103913/How-to-Create-a-Custom-Jumplist-with-Custom-Events

Comment: @FaizanRabbani I have been exploring on this and did not find any starting point for this. I'm wondering if this a tough task or easy ones.

Comment: I have given you a starting point, go through it.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani I asaw the link you provided but does Jumplist work for any OS?

Comment: You will have to see it yourself. I can't provide you with a silver bullet if that is what you are looking for. Research, try to implement and share the code if you encounter any problem.

Comment: The very first sentence in both links answers your question -  _"Windows 7 introduced a new set of features - one of them  is the Jumplist"_ and _"This feature is called a JumpList and is for Windows 7"_